# Optimization of Eloquent queries in Laravel 4

Tags: php, performance, optimization, laravel-4, eloquent

I've just recently started using Laravel and I've got a problem, that my page is really slow.
The issue is that my queries are not ideal:

`

```
<div class="container">
  @foreach ($product as $single) 
    <?php
      $tagy = $single->tags()->get();
      echo "<div class='item";
      foreach($tagy as $tag) {
        $premenna = Tags::where('id','=',$tag->tagID)->first();
        echo " item".$premenna->id;
      }
      echo "'>";
    ?>
      <div class="thumbnail porfolio">
        <a href="/product/{{ $single->id }}"><img class="image" src="<?=Croppa::url($single->destinationPath.'/'.$single->coverphoto, 250)?>" /></a>
        <div class="caption">
          <div class="info">
            <a href="/product/{{ $single->id }}"><h4 style="font-weight: bold;">{{ $single->name }}</h5></a>
            <p style="font-size: 15px; margin-bottom: 0px;">{{ $single->city }}</p>
            <p class="date">{{ $single->date }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="map-location">
            <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q={{$single->gpsn}},{{$single->gpse}}&ll={{$single->gpsn}},{{$single->gpse}}=17" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="tagy">
              <?php 
                  foreach($tagy as $tag) {
                    $variable= Tags::where('id','=',$tag->tagID)->orderBy('name')->first();
                    echo "<a class='hashtag tag".$variable->id."'>".$variable->name." </a>";
                  }
              ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>`
```

This is my Controller function:

```
protected function index()
{
    $product = Product::where('active','=',1)->orderBy('date')->get();
    $tagy = Tags::orderBy('name')->get();

    return View::make('uvod',['product' => $product, 'tags' => $tagy]);
}
```

I've made one-to-many relationship between Product Class and ProductTag Class - that's the fucntion tags();

Could you please somehow help me optimizing the code (queries)? I would like to use @foreach function only once if possible - when i deleted the foreach functions inside the main one the page speed significantly improved.

Thank you very much for any kind of help :)

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: I have got 3 tables: Product(id,name,gpsn,gpse,city,author,coauthors,active);Tags(id,name);ProductTag(id,tagID,product_id)

Comment: hi @matus.kozuch follow the tutorial http://codeplanet.io/laravel-model-relationships-pt-1/. I think you will get your answer from Many-to-Many relations section in that tutorial. If you don't understand it then let me know

Comment: You should define correct relations and use eager loading. You also know get tags in controller and don't use them in views and run multiple queries in view what is not the best solution